# What does SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; do

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

what does SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; do. Because when I was in sqlite I have used this command. Now when Ichanged my database to sqlite all my employee id which has many references in table is set to manual employee code.

```
Employee Id: 4606

Manual employee code: 10002
```

So value in Salaryslip table must be 4606 for employee id but now its 10002

Comment: is it a sqlite command or mysql???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is session-based, when set the way you did in your question.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html

According to this, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS is "Both" for scope. This means it can be set for session:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

or globally:

SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;